# Building a Martingale Apps, and the code is just not working

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build an app the will tell you if you win or lose base on the Martingale on gambling.

My concept is this, you can set your money, target and the minimum bet.

for example is i set my current money is 1000, and my target is to get 1100, and the minimum bet is 100, the app will show me whether I win or not.

Actually my idea was to build this app to calculate the win rate for this, but I didn't know how, therefore I just try to build the simpler app first and further modify if I can get it.

But when I try to run the app, the app keeps showing "You Lose", even I try to create a situation that I have really low chance to lose, still it show me "You Lose".

My Java Code here

```
package com.example.android.gambling;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void seeRate(View view) {

        EditText cMoney = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.money);
        double currentMoney = Double.parseDouble(cMoney.getText().toString());

        EditText target = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.target);
        double theTarget = Double.parseDouble(target.getText().toString());

        EditText bet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bet);
        double minBet = Double.parseDouble(bet.getText().toString());

        String findRate = calRate(currentMoney, theTarget, minBet);

        TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textview.setText("You " + findRate);



    }

    public String calRate(double currentMoney, double theTarget, double minBet) {

        while (currentMoney>minBet){
            boolean win = winRate();
            if (win){
                currentMoney += minBet;
                minBet = minBet;
            }
            else {
                currentMoney -= minBet;
                minBet *= 2;
            }
            if (currentMoney>=theTarget){
                break;
            }

        }

        return "Lose";
    }

    private boolean winRate() {
        double d = Math.random();
        if (d < 0.5)
        return true;
        else
            return false;

    }
}
```

and the xml is here

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.gambling.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/money"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:hint="Current Money"
        android:width="300dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/target"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/money"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:hint="Target"
        android:width="300dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/bet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/target"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:hint="Minimun Bet per Time"
        android:width="300dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Check Rate"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="seeRate"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bet" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Result Here"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Don't you worry that in your code there is no way of returning `Win` from `calRate` method?

Comment: Hi Divers, thanks you for your commend, i just amend the break to return "win" and it works, thanks you very much !!

sorry for my stupid question, and wasting the forum resources...

Comment: Mark my answer as a right one, in order to close question then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code:

```
public String calRate(double currentMoney, double theTarget, double minBet) {
    while (currentMoney > minBet) {
        boolean win = winRate();
        if (win) {
            currentMoney += minBet;
        } else {
            currentMoney -= minBet;
        }
        if (currentMoney >= theTarget) {
            return "Won";
        }
    }
    return "Lose";
}
```

Comment: Hi, Drivers, i have another question...

now i trying to let the app run the function for example like 10 times, to calculate the win Rate, but i stucked here, how i can retrieve the result and to show the percentage?

    public int winPercentage (){
        
        for (int i=1; i<=10; i++){

        }
        return
    }

Comment: Please ask create another topic for another question, and close that one with marking answer as a right one.